# Chart. js shape coloring

Tags: javascript, charts, point, fill

I have a chart I created with Chart.js. In this chart, I have four points and these points are connected and a quadrilateral is obtained and the inside is colored green. But in this way, the y-axis points are painted higher even though they are lower, and the right place remains unpainted even though the points are lower. How can this unpainted area be painted?

```js
 var ctx = document.getElementById('workingLimitGraph').getContext('2d');
        var minFluidOutletTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MinFluidOutletTemp;
        var maxFluidOutletTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MaxFluidOutletTemp;
        var minAmbientTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MinAmbientTemp;
        var maxAmbientTemp = @Model.SerieLimits.Cooling_MaxAmbientTemp;
        //added/subtracted values to expand chart axis values
        var xAxisMin = minFluidOutletTemp - 5;
        var xAxisMax = maxFluidOutletTemp + 5;
        var yAxisMin = minAmbientTemp - 10;
        var yAxisMax = maxAmbientTemp + 10;

        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: [
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp }
                    ],
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
                    showLine: true
                }]
            },
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Water Outlet Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 1,
                            padding: 20,
                        },
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        min: xAxisMin,
                        max: xAxisMax,
                        stepSize: 1,
                    },
                    y: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Ambient Air Temperature (°C)'
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            stepSize: 10,
                            padding: 20,
                        },
                        min: yAxisMin,
                        max: yAxisMax,
                        stepSize: 10,
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // X ekseninin etiketlerini oluşturma
        var xAxisLabels = [];
        for (var i = minFluidOutletTemp - 3; i <= maxFluidOutletTemp + 3; i += 1) {
            xAxisLabels.push(i);
        }

        myChart.data.labels = xAxisLabels;
        // Y ekseninin etiketlerini oluşturma
        var yAxisLabels = [];
        for (var i = yAxisMin; i <= yAxisMax; i += 10) {
            yAxisLabels.push(i);
        }
        myChart.options.scales.y.ticks.callback = function (value, index, values) {
            return value;
        };
```

[image: result]

Comment: Hi Bilge, welcome to SO! Could I ask you to include the HTML in your snippet so that we have a fully working example? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure Correct Order of Data Points**
eg.

```
var data = [
{ x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp }, // Point 1
{ x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp }, // Point 2
{ x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp }, // Point 3
{ x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp } // Point 4
```

];

**Configure fill Option**

```
fill: true;
```

**specify backgroundColor**

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)',
```

Ensure the y-axis scale is correctly configured to accommodate the range of your data points. This seems to be correctly set in your code with min: `yAxisMin` and max: `yAxisMax`.

Ensure you are using a version of Chart.js that supports the features you are using. The `fill` option and dataset configuration are well-supported in Chart.js 2.x and later.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code on other pages, only my axis values are different. It works completely correctly on those pages. When I edited the code as follows, this time it connected 4 points correctly and created a rectangle, but this time it made the inside of this shape completely unpainted.
Code:

```js
data: [
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: maxAmbientTemp },
                        { x: maxFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp },
                        { x: minFluidOutletTemp, y: minAmbientTemp }
                    ],
```

I added one more dot in data and the shape is correct. But I cannot paint this shape.

[This is the final version. How can I edit the code to paint inside this shape?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zq6k.png)